# Why is being one of the close voters not enough to reopen a question with just my vote?

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

A better phrasing is probably: why isn't a vote for reopen equal to retracting a vote for closing?

It makes sense that I can't just pick a random closed question and reopen it with just my vote, but why can't I reopen a question which has *me* as one of the closers? Is there a rationale behind this non-special case?

I'm assuming the reason is not *you've been stupid/hurried to vote for closing, so you don't deserve the right to reopen*, which would exactly describe the situation I find myself in.

Comment: Why should your single reopen vote be able to override the close votes of two other users?

Comment: @yivi, well, the other votes could just be preserved, in theory.

Comment: It's a question of symmetry IMO. If you coudn't close it single-handedly, why should you be able to reopen it by yourself?

Comment: I see. What you want is the ability to “undo” your close vote, removing as if it had never been cast. That would put the question below the closing threshold, and retain the other close votes. You can retract your close vote before the question is closed, but not after. Maybe you should edit your question for clarity.

Comment: @yivi, the point is that [it's not my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65607160/5825294) and I'm just the wannabe answerer who closed the question before thinking enough about it :(

Comment: That's understandable, but I think the primary take-away from this experience should be to just hold off on casting a vote (to close, reopen, delete, etc) until you're sure about the decision. I think the current system is quite reasonable when votes are cast that way.

Comment: @cigien, you're right, I should have thought about it more carefully before voting to close.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you've single-handedly closed a question (either because you hold a gold tag badge or because you have diamond moderator privileges), then you can single-handedly reopen the question.

Otherwise, you cannot, simply because the closure of the question was not unilateral. Your vote was not the only one that mattered. It was only one of the three. Your later decision to reopen the question should not nullify the opinions of the other two close voters. In order to override their decision, there needs to be some form of consensus—like two other people agreeing that it should be reopened.

Closure and reopening are meant to be perfectly inverse (symmetrical) processes.

Comment: I see. Probably I was expecting that reopening was the inverse of closing, rather than parallel.

Comment: It *is* the inverse. I don't see how that changes anything. In fact, "inverse" is an even more apt term than "parallel". I'm going to steal that and update my answer.

Comment: By inverse I mean something which can be obtained by reversing the process. And I cannot **reverse** my vote to close a question. Reversing it would mean that the count of votes is decremented by 1 and the question is reopened with as many votes for closing it as necessary to close it minus 1.

Comment: You can reverse your vote, but it doesn't eliminate the votes of the other two users who thought it should be closed. Why should it? Note that you can *retract* your vote to close before the question actually gets closed. Perhaps that is what you're thinking of?

Comment: Yes. That's my point, thanks for helping phrasing it. I expected that voting for reopening was equivalent to retracting my vote for closing.

Comment: No, once the question actually gets closed (consensus of 3 voters), the transaction is considered complete. Reopening is then a separate process that must be undertaken.

Comment: @Enlico retracting your vote on a *closed* question would be problematic. Imagine this situation - you find a question that lacks debugging details. You vote to close and two others also do. Now the question is updated - you think it's enough, so you retract your vote, which makes the question open with two pending close votes on it. It's possible that the votes (and likely comments that are now irrelevant) mislead somebody into casting another close vote. This would re-close the question immediately.

Comment: Also you should think about this: once the question is closed it is no longer possible for other users to cast additional close-votes even if they think the question closeworthy. So perhaps your vote would not have been one of three but one of 100 (of which 97 would not have been registered). This does of course not apply before the question is actually closed, so the situation isn't symmetric from the start.

Answer (score 6):

If you regret your vote, you're perfectly free to retract it before the question is closed. Apart from that, you need to get other people to agree with you that your original vote was wrong.

Consider it this way: if a question is closed, then obviously two other people agreed that it should be closed. What should happen if you later regret the vote and the other close voters don't regret it? Would it be "fair" that you could unilaterally overrule the other two voters just because you changed your mind?

One other issue: if that was allowed, you could vote to close a question that you don't think should be closed just so that you could unilaterally reopen it later.